# emacs で、シェルの末尾の改行のエスケープをそろえたい

Tags: emacs

シェルスクリプトを記述していると、コマンドが長くなるので、バックスラッシュ`\`でエスケープしながら改行して、複数行でひとつのコマンドを記述することがあります。

```
aws ec2 run-instances --image-id ami-1233456 \
    --instance-type t2.medium \
    --subnet-id subnet-deadbeaf \
    --security-group-ids sg-123abbbb \
    --key-name "The Key"
```

この、末尾の改行エスケープをそろえたいです。

```
aws ec2 run-instances --image-id ami-1233456 \
    --instance-type t2.medium                \
    --subnet-id subnet-deadbeaf              \
    --security-group-ids sg-123abbbb         \
    --key-name "The Key"
```

これを手で実行するのはつらいので、一括で実行する方法などありませんでしょうか。

Comment: region を指定して `sh-backslash-region` を実行してみて下さい。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

region を指定して `sh-backslash-region` でいけました。

Answer (score 2):

`align-regexp`を使えば自由な正規表現で文字列を揃えられます。
`\`、数字、`--`、`:`、`=`、なんでもありです。
正規表現入力の手間はありますが...